# how to query date-string field

Tags: elasticsearch

Elaticsearch 7.x. The mapping contain field "created" of type "text", but actually it stores dates in format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". In theory range query for string is supported but I cannot make it working

```
{
   "range": {
      "created": {
         "gt": "2024-01-01 00:00:00"
      }
   }
}
```

tried various combinations and usually it returns all docs.
What options do I have? I found I cannot change the type, also I cannot remove and add as new field  with date type

Comment: I think you could use `script` to parse your string to date and then compare inside script but it would be less convenient than `range` operations for date fields

Comment: You need to create a new index and store those dates as a `date` type, not as `text`, it's never going to work the way you like because `text` strings are tokenized

Comment: I cannot created new index, in the end I'll add new fields but did some tests and save data in a format so I've only one token like 20230925T141312. Also tried adding dots. In general query for dates parts seems to be working but if using time like greater 20230925T150000 not. And I'm wondering why?

Comment: I think if the type is text its not a date object although it looks like date object and you can not use gte and lte here.